# Sending commands over ssh with parameters

Tags: unix, shell, scripting

I am trying to send a command over ssh with a parameter but the shell fails to expand the command properly any ideas what am i doing wrong with this

```
for i in 71 72 73 74 75
do
    for server in server1 server2
    do
        somestr="Some String"
        echo "$server hdiskpower$i \c" ; ssh $server "lsattr -El hdiskpower$i |grep $somestr "
    done
done
```

Comment: Dennis thanks for the edit the script is more readable now

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing some variable to remote server inside a command, then those variable must be defined at that remote server.

Like, if you hardcoded the command in script like 
`"echo "$server hdiskpower$i \c" ; 
ssh $server lsattr -El hdiskpower71 |grep XYZ"` then it surely works for you.

Meanwhile i will work to make it workable with variables.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `-t` parameter to set ssh to use pseudo-tty. If you'd like to run that command on a remote machine, you'd do it by

```
ssh $server -t "lsattr -El hdiskpower$i|grep $somestr"
```

Comment: Nope it still says grep: 0652-033 Cannot open volume.
I am on AIX if that matters

Comment: Since it's an error reported by grep, the problem is in the command you are sending. If you run that exact same command on the remote machine without the ssh, does it work? For example `lsattr -El hdiskpower71|grep "somethingsomething"`.

Comment: yes it works without ssh and if hardcode the values instead of variables

Comment: Interesting. What if you try it with some other command just to test grep, for example `ssh $server -t "echo \"test\"|grep test"`?

Comment: ssh $server -t "echo \"test\"|grep test"
This works and i get the result test

Comment: Its strange that if i do ssh $server -t "lsattr -El hdiskpower$i|grep hardcodedstring "
it works. So its definately gotta do something with variable expansion i guess

Comment: Okay, so the problem is probably in your `$somestr`. Can you say that the variable contains? If it contains special characters such as `<, >, "` you must escape them with `\`.

Comment: well it containts spaces but nothing else something like 
Physical Volume Identifier

Comment: Yes, there's your problem. If you make a variable for the search string you have to escape it for whitespace also. So if your $string would be `string="Physical Volume Identifier"` you'd have to escape it as `string="Physical\ Volume\ Identifier"`. Another option is to escape the string before `grep`: `ssh $server -t "lsattr -El hdiskpower$i|grep \"$somestr\""`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:
At first you need to install `sshpass` on your machine.
then you can write your own script:

```
while read pass port user ip; do
sshpass -p$pass ssh -p $port $user@$ip <<ENDSSH1
    COMMAND 1
    .
    .
    .
    COMMAND n
ENDSSH1
done <<____HERE
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP
      .      .       .       .
      .      .       .       .
      .      .       .       .
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP    
____HERE
```